# Mapped buttons that have opacity of 0 are showing, and are overlapping when resizing the window

Tags: reactjs

I've successfully mapped over text and have styled it with transition effects when going from one slide to the next as you can see here:

[image]

Following a similar concept with buttons isn't working. There should only be one button active per slide like you see here:

[image]

I want the buttons to have the same effect as the text, but I'm getting behaviors like you see here:

[image]

As you can see, there is no transition effect on the button when clicking to the second slide, and it also appears in a lower spot.

And lastly, when resizing the window, buttons are overlapping like you see here:

[image]

Don't know what to try next.

Here's the ImageSlider component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { SliderData } from "../data";
import { categories } from "../data";
import ShopNowButtonActive from "./ShopNowButtonActive";
import { IoIosArrowBack } from "react-icons/io";
import { IoIosArrowForward } from "react-icons/io";
import "./ImageSlider.css";
import ShopNowButton from "./ShopNowButton";

const ImageSlider = ({ slides }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="slider">
      <IoIosArrowBack className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide} />
      {SliderData.map((slide, index) => (
        <div key={slide.id}>
          <img
            src={slide.img}
            alt=""
            className={index === current ? "slide active" : "slide"}
          />
          <div className="info-container">
            <div className={index === current ? "title active" : "title"}>
              {slide.title}
            </div>
            <div className={index === current ? "desc active" : "desc"}>
              {slide.desc}
            </div>
            {categories.map((item, index) =>
              index === current ? (
                <ShopNowButtonActive item={item} />
              ) : (
                <ShopNowButton item={item} />
              )
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <IoIosArrowForward className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

The css file:

```
.slider {
  height: 90vh;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.left-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 32px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 88%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0% 0%);
}

.slide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms opacity ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 88%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0% 0%);
}

.info-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 30px;
}

.title.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 700ms;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.title {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.desc.active {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  transition-delay: 700ms;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.desc {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 32px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The ShopNowButtonActive component:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ButtonActive = styled.button`
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  width: 8rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-delay: 700ms;
`;

const ShopNowButtonActive = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/products/${item.cat}`}>
      <ButtonActive>SHOP NOW</ButtonActive>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default ShopNowButtonActive;
```

And finally, the ShopNowButton component:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Button = styled.button`
  opacity: 0;
  /* display: none; */
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  width: 8rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
`;

const ShopNowButton = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/products/${item.cat}`}>
      <Button>SHOP NOW</Button>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default ShopNowButton;
```

(Sorry for the use of both an external css file and styled components.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any workaround or the issue still exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated the above scenario using some static data. I have modified some of the css. It is working as expected. I also observed that the only major difference between ShopNowButton and ShopNowButtonActive was opacity property which hides the element. The reason you are observing 2 buttons because they were all there in the dom actually.(They were not hiding properly due to which we are observing more shop now buttons and every time we click on next icon the corresponding button is being displayed. Basically all the buttons are there on the page itself.)

Please find the sandbox url below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-6u05e7?file=/src/ImageSlider/ImageSlider.js

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your explanation with all the buttons being in the dom whether active or not and that I may not be properly hiding the inactive buttons with opacity: 0. I looked at the your code in the sandbox, but I still don't see how I can achive the effect I'm looking for. I would like to do what you see on this site's landing page: https://www.llsupply.ca/ And each button on each slide needs to direct you to a page for that category.

Comment: I understood. But actually I can't replicate the scenario entirely from your snippet actually as I don't have much information on the what data is provided. So as per the question I have fixed styling issues. Now as you asked we need to redirect to particular url I have added some static urls. On clicking buttons we will see the url navigation. I simply can't create individual components for categories because I don't know the entire picture. I took care of the things what was asked in the question.